# Force apt-get to overwrite file installed by another package

Tags: apt, dpkg

(I realize a similar question was asked before but the answers there don't handle these details)

I'm on Ubuntu 10.10 and need both python2.5 (coming from deadnsakes -- https://launchpad.net/~fkrull/+archive/deadsnakes) and python-profiler

Unfortunately, these two packages both try to install /usr/lib/python2.5/profile.py so apt-get won't allow me to install both

Obviously this is a packaging bug, but I need this fixed asap. Is there anyway to completely ignore these errors and just blow out that file?

Comment: It is not necessarily a bug: the two packages can be incompatible.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

After python2.5 is installed try running:

```
sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" install python-profiler
```

This should pass the `--force-overwrite` flag to the underlying dpkg instance which will tell dpkg to overwrite one package's file with anothers.

[source](http://raphaelhertzog.com/2011/08/01/understanding-dpkgs-file-overwrite-error/)

Comment: I should have mentioned that if you just have a .deb file, you can just run: `sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite python-profiler.deb`