# Reinstalling all installed debs with a command

Tags: command-line, system-installation

Is there a way to reinstall all installed (.deb) packages with a terminal command. I think some package is corrupted (I don't know which) and I don't want to reinstall the OS (which will need a lot of energy and time to recusotomize).

Comment: "I think some package is corrupted" why? and re-installing probably will not fix that ;)

Comment: I have a problem with keyboard http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/130772/giving-more-priority-to-a-usb-device and some bash scripts run by hotkeys no longer work. The solution is reinstalltion of the OS. But I want to try other things.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to understand a few things.

First, apt-get / dpkg / apt , by default, will not overwrite configuration files if they already exist.

You can over ride this behavior.

```
sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" install python-profiler
```

see : [Force apt-get to overwrite file installed by another package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56761/force-apt-get-to-overwrite-file-installed-by-another-package)

This is one of the reasons why, unlike other OS perhaps, re-installing a package typically will not fix a problem.

You can purge and re-install a package, as purge will remove config files.

But even a purge will not remove config files in your home directory.

Second, unless you manually edited a system file, reinstalling will not help as you did not really change anything. This is because user specific settings are stored in $HOME .

Third, custom configuration files, for your keyboard or other settings etc, reside in your home directory. These user files will not change by re-installing a package, you need to delete or edit the files manually.

Fourth, nothing in the question you linked suggested re-installing your entire system would fix your problem.

To debug your problem, identify your hardware and check your logs for errors.

Comment: The last comment there proves that the man problem is with the OS.