# How can I change location of soffice in openoffice 4.1.3?

Tags: openoffice.org

I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and have previously removed libreoffice and installed openoffice 4.1.3.

I keep getting dependency problems and none of the software is able to update anymore.

Seems related to libreoffice still in system somewhere.

The following is received when `apt-get -f install` is run

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libreoffice-common
Suggested packages:
  libreoffice-style-breeze libreoffice-style-hicontrast
  libreoffice-style-human libreoffice-style-oxygen libreoffice-style-sifr
  libreoffice-style-tango
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libreoffice-common
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 249 not upgraded.
8 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/22.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 84.8 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 296107 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libreoffice-common_1%3a5.1.4-0ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-common (1:5.1.4-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-common_1%3a5.1.4-0ubuntu1_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/soffice', which is also in package openoffice-debian-menus 4.1.3-9783
rmdir: failed to remove '/var/lib/libreoffice/share/prereg/': No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove '/var/lib/libreoffice/share/': No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove '/var/lib/libreoffice/program/': No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove '/var/lib/libreoffice': No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove '/var/lib/libreoffice': No such file or directory
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20160701-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.5-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-icon-theme (3.12.0-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-common_1%3a5.1.4-0ubuntu1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: your problem is the package openoffice-debian-menus I think. What is this package? How did you install or create it?

Comment: I downloaded the openoffice 4.1.3 package and installed it from the terminal. I think I used dpkg command.

Comment: I don't think openoffice is compatible with recent versions of Ubuntu... Libreoffice has very much replaced it as the go-to office suite. You may be fighting a tough battle with this. I would suggest removing openoffice and reinstalling Libreoffice...

Comment: Did you remove all components of Libre-office?

Comment: You can try overwriting the file. Use this solution http://askubuntu.com/a/56764/61218

Comment: I've had trouble removing them. Managed to list them but I can't seem to remove them all. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. I have in fact been able to install manually LibreOffice 5.2, but I still have unmet dependencies from the pre-installed LibreOffice which I originally removed.

Comment: Will check out the overwriting solution, thanks.