# The following packages have unmet dependencies python 3.7

Tags: package-management, upgrade, dependencies, python3

Randomly got this error while trying to `sudo apt-get upgrade` and already tried to run  `apt-get -f` install without success, what should i do?

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpython3.7-stdlib : Depends: libpython3.7-minimal (= 3.7.3-1+xenial1) but 3.7.3-2~16.04.york0 is installed
 python3.7 : Depends: libpython3.7-stdlib (= 3.7.3-2~16.04.york0) but 3.7.3-1+xenial1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

edit:

`apt policy python3.7 libpython3.7-stdlib libpython3.7-minimal` output

```
python3.7:
  Installed: 3.7.3-2~16.04.york0
  Candidate: 3.7.3-2~16.04.york0
  Version table:
 *** 3.7.3-2~16.04.york0 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.7/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.7.3-1+xenial1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
libpython3.7-stdlib:
  Installed: 3.7.3-1+xenial1
  Candidate: 3.7.3-2~16.04.york0
  Version table:
     3.7.3-2~16.04.york0 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.7/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
 *** 3.7.3-1+xenial1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libpython3.7-minimal:
  Installed: 3.7.3-2~16.04.york0
  Candidate: 3.7.3-2~16.04.york0
  Version table:
 *** 3.7.3-2~16.04.york0 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.7/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.7.3-1+xenial1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

`sudo apt install libpython3.7-stdlib` output

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  python3.7-distutils python3.7-lib2to3
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libpython3.7-stdlib
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1748 kB of archives.
After this operation, 91,1 kB disk space will be freed.
(Reading database ... 303775 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libpython3.7-stdlib_3.7.3-2~16.04.york0_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython3.7-stdlib:amd64 (3.7.3-2~16.04.york0) over (3.7.3-1+xenial1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libpython3.7-stdlib_3.7.3-2~16.04.york0_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/__init__.py', which is also in package python3.7-distutils 3.7.3-1+xenial1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libpython3.7-stdlib_3.7.3-2~16.04.york0_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and add the output of `apt policy python3.7 libpython3.7-stdlib libpython3.7-minimal` please?

Comment: Have you been getting packages from here and if so how were at least 1 installed??  https://cloudsmith.io/~agriconnect/repos/debian/packages/?q=tag%3Alatest

Comment: @doug i haven't

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the output of `sudo apt install libpython3.7-stdlib` ?

Comment: Ok, so 2 python3 ppa's with conflicting package contents. See this answer as how to force an overwrite with apt-get. https://askubuntu.com/questions/56761/force-apt-get-to-overwrite-file-installed-by-another-package

Comment: @doug ran `sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" install libpython3.7-stdlib` like  you said and it seemed to solve the problem, thx

Comment: @doug can you try to explain how this could have happened, did i install something i shouldn't?

Comment: No you. For some reason the 2 ppa's produced the same file '/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/__init__.py'  in 2 different packages. Why this occurred don't know, one would need to grab both sources and debian files to see why. By default apt/apt-get or dpkg will not overwrite a same name file from another package. I seem to remember this happening from time to time with the york ppa..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Diagnosing:

See what `sudo apt upgrade` says:

```
myself@box:~$ sudo apt upgrade
[sudo] password for myself: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpython3.7-stdlib : Depends: libpython3.7-minimal (= 3.7.13-1+bionic1) but 3.7.13-1+bionic3 is installed
 python3.7 : Depends: libpython3.7-stdlib (= 3.7.13-1+bionic3) but 3.7.13-1+bionic1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Conclusion: something is wrong with some Python 3.7 packages.

---

### Overview - one Python version:

List all the Python 3.7 packages. Good to compare this listing before and after you implement the solution.

```
# Command:
sudo dpkg -l | grep 'python3\.7' | awk '{print $2}'

# Output:
libpython3.7-minimal:amd64
libpython3.7-stdlib:amd64
python3.7
python3.7-distutils
python3.7-lib2to3
python3.7-minimal
python3.7-venv
```

### Solution - one Python version:

No need to remove/purge the deadsnakes ppa. This worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04

1. Issue this command to delete all Python 3.7 packages:

   ```
    myself@box:~$ sudo apt --fix-missing purge $(dpkg -l | grep 'python3\.7' | awk '{print $2}')
   ```
2. Answer `Y` to execute the removal of the listed packages.
3. Install the same packages again:

   - Alternative A) SLOWER AND SMARTER VERSION: Install only the packages you know you want to install, they will be set by apt as manually installed:

     ```
      myself@box:~$ sudo apt install python3.7 python3.7-venv
     ```

     and see if the other packages are installed automatically as dependencies. If not, install the other missing packages manually, too.
   - Alternative B) FASTER AND DUMBER VERSION: Copy the package names from the list created by `apt --fix-missing purge`, remove the stars and install them (again):

     ```
     myself@box:~$ sudo apt install libpython3.7-minimal libpython3.7-stdlib python3.7 python3.7-minimal python3.7-venv
     ```
4. Not a must: check with the **Overview**-command from above that you have the same packages installed now, as before implementing the solution.

---

### Overview - several Python versions:

List all the packages for all the Python-versions needed, for me 3.7, 3.10 and 3.11. Good to compare this listing before and after you implement the solution.

```
sudo dpkg -l | grep 'python3\.7\|python3\.10\|python3\.11' | awk '{print $2}'
```

### Solution - several Python versions at once:

1. Do as above, but use this command instead. Fill in the Python versions that are failing. For me they were 3.7, 3.10 and 3.11

   ```
    sudo apt --fix-missing purge $(dpkg -l | grep 'python3\.7\|python3\.10\|python3\.11' | awk '{print $2}')
   ```
2. Answer `Y`
3. Install the Pythons again. I did not have/need venv for 3.11, so:

   ```
    sudo apt install python3.11 python3.10 python3.10-venv python3.7 python3.7-venv
   ```
4. Not a must: check with the **Overview**-command from above that you have the same packages installed now, as before implementing the solution.

---

Source and explanation of each part of the command (#1) are found here https://askubuntu.com/a/1402567

Comment: This should be voted as an answer. Most people may only need the "Solution - one Python version" section.

Comment: You are probably right, @fchen, about that most people need the one Python version solution. However, I myself needed also the several versions method, the second time this happened for me. I did not find a question concerning several Python versions, so I added it here.

Answer (score 2):

Consider to remove the problematic PPA and reinstall normal packages with:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:jonathonf/python-3.7
sudo ppa-purge ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libpython3.5-minimal python3-minimal python3.5-minimal
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libpython3-stdlib libpython3.5-stdlib
```

Comment: `sudo ppa-purge ppa:deadsnakes/ppa` helped for me.  After that, `sudo apt --fix-broken install` worked.  Then, I added deadsnakes ppa back and everything seemed to be working ok.

Answer (score 1):

OK, it seems you used another PPA with higher version of the package and then removed it from your `sources.list`. It is not possible to make apt to downgrade the whole package version. So you need to fallback to the PPA that you have used:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/python-3.7
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: "It is not possible to make apt to downgrade the whole package version." Why do you think so? Downgrading to a specific version that is either available from a repo or as .deb is very well possible.

Comment: @ByteCommander, for specific package is possible. But for whole python packages is not possible as far as I know.

Comment: @Olimjon tried what you suggested but i still get the same error, this is really weird because everything was fine just yesterday and i didn't change anything