# Running Software Updater got libpython3.7 umet dependencies error

Tags: package-management, upgrade, dpkg, dependencies, update-manager

Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

I was trying to run Software Updater but got the following errors:

```
libpython3.7: Depends: libpython3.7-stdlib (= 3.7.13-1+focal3) but it is not installed
              Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.0) but 1:1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu1.3 is installed
libpython3.7-dev: Depends: libpython3.7-stdlib (= 3.7.13-1+focal3) but it is not installed
                  Depends: libpython3.7 (= 3.7.13-1+focal3) but 3.7.13-1+focal3 is installed
python3.7: Depends: python3.7-minimal (= 3.7.13-1+focal3) but 3.7.13-1+focal3 is installed
           Depends: libpython3.7-stdlib (= 3.7.13-1+focal3) but it is not installed
```

I tried the following methods but none of them worked.

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
sudo apt upgrade
```

```
sudo apt-get purge python3.7
sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get install python3.7*
```

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue while trying to upgrade Ansible from the ppa.

I removed python using the advice in this issue:
[The following packages have unmet dependencies python 3.7](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1141955/the-following-packages-have-unmet-dependencies-python-3-7)

```
 sudo apt --fix-missing purge $(dpkg -l | grep 'python3\.7' | awk '{print $2}')
```

Then ran `apt upgrade` and the issue appears to be resolved.