# can't install updates and got the package system is broken with unmet dependencies

Tags: 20.04, python

I can't install updates and start getting the following error on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS. It looks like python package issue. How can I solve it?

[image]

Comment: Are you using third party repositories ? Please run `sudo apt update`and `sudo apt upgrade` and copy/paste the results into your original question.

Comment: By the way, 14,04 is EOL and not supported.

Comment: @SorenA According to [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases), 20.04.4 LTS EOL is April 2030. The tag was wrong, my bad.

Comment: The 14.04 comment might have been for an other question ... sorry

Comment: @Sithu, community support for Ubuntu 20.04 ends in 2025. After that, we won't answer questions about it anymore. After the end of community support, Canonical has committed to provide free security patches until 2030, but they won't answer questions or provide other forms of *support* for free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1404848/177906, I resolved the issue as below.

deleted all Python 3.7 packages:

```
sudo apt --fix-missing purge $(dpkg -l | grep 'python3\.7' | awk '{print $2}')
```

and installed the same packages again:

```
sudo apt install libpython3.7-minimal libpython3.7-stdlib python3.7 python3.7-minimal python3.7-venv
```