# Software updater ubuntu 20.04 LTS : package broken

Tags: 20.04, package-management, python

When I run the automatic Ubuntu software update, I get the following message (see below).
I installed Python 3.7 by myself when I install the OS : so I have python 3.8 and 3.7 in the same time on my pc. Until now, I had met no issue. Can you help me about the process I must follow please. It seems to be an issue with focal1 and focal3 version ?

```
The package system is broken
Check if you are using third party repositories. If so disable them, since they are a common source of problems.
Furthermore run the following command in a Terminal: apt-get install -f
Transaction failed: The package system is broken
```

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
libpython3.7-stdlib: Depends: libpython3.7-minimal (= 3.7.13-1+focal1) but 3.7.13-1+focal3 is installed
                 Depends: libcrypt1 (>= 1:4.1.0) but 1:4.4.10-10ubuntu4 is installed
                 Depends: liblzma5 (>= 5.1.1alpha+20120614) but 5.2.4-1ubuntu1.1 is installed
                 Depends: libncursesw6 (>= 6) but 6.2-0ubuntu2 is installed
                 Depends: libreadline8 (>= 7.0~beta) but 8.0-4 is installed
                 Depends: libsqlite3-0 (>= 3.7.15) but 3.31.1-4ubuntu0.2 is installed
                 Depends: libtinfo6 (>= 6) but 6.2-0ubuntu2 is installed
python3.7: Depends: python3.7-minimal (= 3.7.13-1+focal3) but 3.7.13-1+focal3 is installed
       Depends: libpython3.7-stdlib (= 3.7.13-1+focal3) but 3.7.13-1+focal1 is installed
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Finally, I found my answer with this post : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1141955/the-following-packages-have-unmet-dependencies-python-3-7 .