# Fatal error: Error while installing package

Tags: apt, package-management

There has been an update around for two weeks which does not install, when I update my packages I get this:

`Fatal error: Error while installing package: trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libsdl2-2.0-0/changelog.Debian.gz', which is different from other instances of package libsdl2-2.0-0`

How to fix this?

`apt-cache policy libsdl2-2.0-0`  gives this:

`libsdl2-2.0-0: Installed: 2.0.8+dfsg1-1ubuntu1.18.04.4 Candidate: 2.0.10+dfsg1-3 Version table: 2.0.10+dfsg1-3 500 500 http://lt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages *** 2.0.8+dfsg1-1ubuntu1.18.04.4 100 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status`

Comment: Try `sudo apt install --reinstall libsdl2-2.0-0`

Comment: got this:

`dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libsdl2-2.0-0_2.0.10+dfsg1-3_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libsdl2-2.0-0/changelog.Debian.gz', which is different from other instances of package libsdl2-2.0-0:amd64
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libsdl2-2.0-0_2.0.10+dfsg1-3_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

Comment: Please edit your question to include the complete output of `apt-cache policy libsdl2-2.0-0`

Comment: question edited

Comment: Looks like your old version is from the 18.04 repositories, and your new version is from the 20.04 repositories. Did you recently run `do-release-upgrade`? Or did your release-upgrade some other way? (Be specific) Or is this not a release-upgrade, but you are mixing package from different versions of Ubuntu?

Comment: sorry I am not able to answer that question because I do not know the answer....

Comment: But I think did the upgrade using GUI. and during the process my laptop died. Since then I have this issue

Comment: is it possible to fix this?

Comment: Easily: [dpkg has a --force-overwrite option](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56761). Is this the *only* problem you have as a result of the poweroff? If there are others, it may be worthwhile to backup your data and reinstall.