# Is there a way to pass flags to dpkg (such as `--force-overwrite`) with Synaptic?

Tags: package-management, dpkg, synaptic

I still use Synaptic for package management, and I'd like to be able to pass arguments such as '--force-overwrite', to avoid certain errors.

Is this possible?

Comment: No, synaptic does not give you that level of granular control over `dpkg` itself.

Comment: To be sure you have to check the real action and purpose of *Settings → Set Internal Option* (check [man-page](https://github.com/mvo5/synaptic/blob/5285d4456e1bd3706290c96b330ed6a604937aa3/man/synaptic.8#L44) and source code.

Comment: @N0rbert this is the option that came to mind, but the man page doesn't give further details about what those 'internal options' are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*** Edit 2024 Jan 21 - Seems not to be work anymore as of latest Ubuntu updates ***

Here is what seems to work in "Set an internal option":

Variable: Dpkg::option
Value: "--force-overwrite"

See picture in link.

[image: Pic: Synaptic "Set Internal Option"]

The syntax follows the way apt-get passes options to dpkg.
(See: [Force apt-get to overwrite file installed by another package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56761/force-apt-get-to-overwrite-file-installed-by-another-package))